# the Cmp operation doesn't work

Tags: assembly, assemblies, inline-assembly

I have problem when I compare the numbers. The code is:

```
cmp edx,[numeroIterazioniColonna]
    je aggiorna
inc edx
```

in [numeroIterazioniColonna] there is the value 4.0 while in the edx there is the value 0 but when my application starts the condition is never true. Anyone can help me?

Comment: What does the entire loop look like?

Comment: 4.0? You mean it's a floating point value? `cmp` is an integer operation, so it won't work with floating point values. Also, why did you expect 4.0 and 0 to be equal?

Comment: @michael do you suggest me which operation I can use?  I try to write a loop !

Comment: Comparing floating points is much more complicated than it appears (try googling: comparing floating point numbers).  Without seeing the entire loop (which Joachim already asked for and you failed to provide), we can only guess at what you are trying to do.  Since numeroIterazioniColonna sounds like some sort of iteration counter, my guess involves changing it to an int.

Answer (score 0):

With integer values:

```
numeroIterazioniColonna DB 4,0,0,0 

      mov edx,0
P1:   cmp edx,[numeroIterazioniColonna]
      je short aggiorna
      inc edx
      jmp P1

aggiorna:
```